# Horrid issues with printing with Anet A6?8?

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-cura, prusa-i3

I just recently got a printer, supposed to be a Prusa i3 Reprap clone. It came with Repetier firmware on it, and its previous owner had no idea about any calibration. I calibrated X-, Y-, and Z-axis along with the extruder, and now when I print a test cube it comes out with the right dimensions. But, the quality is horrible.

I'm printing with 30 mm/s speed as shells, 15 mm/s as infill, infill percentage is above 60 %. I've tried everything I can think of, including suffering a temperature tower (which came out just wrong). What am I missing?

[image: failed print 1]
[[image: failed print 2][2]]

Comment: Looks like it is printed way too hot, what is the temperature setting? I'm curious what the real temperature of extrusion was.

Comment: I used 200 for this. 8th image in the below link is my attempt at a temperature tower from 220 to 180 in 450 layers.
https://imgur.com/a/zHI6TpO

Comment: How did you "calibrate" those? Hopefully not by measuring printed parts?

Comment: By using G1 and measuring the distance travelled with a caliper really. I'm familiar with their internal firmware.

By the way, problem has been solved. What the seller advertised & I thought was a 0.4mm nozzle. In reality, it was so beat up that it was 1.2mm. New nozzle & everything works great.

Comment: For the community, could you turn you comment with the solution into an answer?  That way, others will benefit from both your problem, and your solution.